# Did I prove the continuity of the exponential function correctly?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was supposed to to proof:

> Given: $exp: \mathbb{R} \ni  x \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }
> > \frac{1}{k!}x^{k} \in  \mathbb{R}$
>
> Prove that $exp$ is continuous in every $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$.

With help of egreg, I think I found a final solution for this:

We are looking at the continuity at the position $x_{0}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. We then need to show that

$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}} e^x = e^{x_{0}}$

For this we take a sequence $x_{n}$ with $\lim_{x_{n}\rightarrow \infty } x_{n} = x_{0}$.

Then: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } e^{x_{n}- x_{0}}=1$

Now by using $e^{a+b} = e^{a} e^{b}$
 we get:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } e^{x_{n}}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } e^{x_{0}}* e^{x_{n}-x_{0}}=$

= $e^{x_{0}} * \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }e^{x_{n}-x_{0}}$ =

= $e^{x_{0}}$

Proof should work, assuming I proved the continuity at $x_{0} = 0$ (I did).

What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, if you know $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a)\exp(b)$ and that $\exp$ is continuous at $0$ then this argument shows it is continuous everywhere else.

Comment: I think there is much simpler way to prove it. Assuming that you know that the sum of a power series in continuous on the interior of the disc of convergence, you just need to prove that the radius of convergence is infinity.